# does modernizr require for HTML5 mobile site?

Tags: html, modernizr

am new to HTML5 and mobile sites... i have few doubts

1) does modernizr required for mobiles site?
2) If i do not use modernizr, will all HTML5 tags support in all mobiles and tabs?

ex:

Comment: mobile browser does't required modernizer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, Modernizr is not required to build mobile sites.
2) Whether you use Modernizr or not there will always be some mobile browsers that won't support HTML5 elements.

Comment: Whether you use Modernizr or not there will always be some mobile browsers that won't support HTML5 elements. - So how can i go with HTML5 for mobile site if it not support in some mobile browsers. Should i develop my mobile site in XHTML1.0? Please give me clarification.

Comment: You have three options. The easiest to develop (but the one that prevents more people from using your site) is to ignore browsers that don't support HTML5. The middle idea is to develop your site entirely in HTML4/XHTML and just do without the HTML5 features. The hardest to develop (but the option that will end up with a better product in the end) is to develop the site with HTML5 and use Modernizr or your own feature detection and fill in any missing functionality using Javascript. The last option is the way I code and the option I would recommend.